# screenshots don't change when layout changes

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager as my main navigation in app. I'm using ActionBar, as well. What I want to achieve is that when user clicks search button in ActionBar I want to have blurred background. So my approach is to take a screenshot, blur it, set as ImageView and display as an overlay over the whole view. And it works. But problem is that actually when I first open search it displays proper screenshot. Then I turn overlay off, change page in `ViewPager`, click search again and ... I can see the previous screenshot- not new one with new page on it. Here are my snippets of code:

1. show and hide overlay on search click (I'm passing `R.id.container` view which is parent id of my content view, menuOverlay is my `ImageView` referenced from layout)
2. Here's my method that takes screenshot and makes it blurry

   // Ad. 1
       item.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem menuItem) {
                       if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {

   ```
   menuOverlay.setImageBitmap(Utils.takeSnapshot(findViewById(R.id.container)));
                   menuOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
               return true;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem menuItem) {
               if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {
                   menuOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
               return true;
           }
       });



   // Ad. 2
   public static Bitmap takeSnapshot(View v) {
           v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           v.buildDrawingCache();
           Bitmap bm = v.getDrawingCache();
           Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, bm.getWidth()/5, bm.getHeight()/5, false);
           return Utils.fastblur(scaled, 5);
       }
   ```

I;m using fast blur algorithm found somewhere here on StackOverflow which is quite fast.
Where's the problem? Why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the answer. if you want to always have "fresh" screenshot you need to destroy cache after all operations:

```
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```